# Migrate a table with laravel, error "MySQL server has gone away" and "Packets out of order"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm making a page with the Laravel 5.4 framework directly on a server to which I'm connected through an SSH session with MobaXterm. I'm trying to migrate a table but I get the following error:

```
   [PDOException]
   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
   [ErrorException]
   Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 45. Packet size=4739923
```

My hosting provider say that my.ini is set to max_allowed_packet=268435456 so the issue must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

The error Message: "[2006] MySQL server has gone away" could also stand for an query timeout.
So my be the 'wait_timeout' in the my.ini should be greater